# The eats are good there and the prices are cheap

Tags: word-usage

Here, "eats" means, informally, "food".

But have you ever heard such a usage? I wonder whether most of native English speakers could understand it.

> **eats**, [plural] Informal. **food**:
> The eats are good there and the prices are cheap.

> Source: Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not used in all English-speaking areas, but it's not uncommon. So, yes it's something most native speakers would understand, even if they wouldn't necessarily use it themselves.